# Creating and Manipulating Cookies Using PHP

Tags: php, html, cookies

Im wotking on a mini project that involves creating an initial cookie (nag) which keeps track how many time the user has visited the page, every fifth time, it prompts the user to register by showing the register form. If they decide to skip it, the counter resets and begins again. However, if the user decides to register, all i need to do is delete the nag cookie, and replace it with a cookie that has the username and one for email. So when the user comes back to the webpage, itll show a msg like `Hello Name (Email)`, instead of the counter and the form.

I managed to get the nag cookie working, but when the user enters the data into the form and registers, the nag cookie starts over instead of being deleted and instead of showing the Hello part, it continues the counter. It also gives me a `Confirm Form Resubmission` panel on Chrome. i cant figure out why.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   setcookie("register", 1);
   $_COOKIE['register'] = 1;
   setcookie("username", $_POST['username']);
   $_COOKIE['username'] = $_POST['username'];
   setcookie("email", $_POST['email']);
   $_COOKIE['email'] = $_POST['email'];
   setcookie("nag","", time()-3600); 
   $_COOKIE['nag'] = time()-3600;
}

    if(isset($_COOKIE['register'])){
        $user = $_COOKIE['username'];
        $email = $_COOKIE['email'];
    }else{
        if(isset($_COOKIE['nag'])) {
                $_COOKIE['nag']--;
            setcookie("nag", $_COOKIE['nag']);
        }else{
            setcookie("nag", 5);
        }
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lab 5</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_COOKIE['register'])){
            echo "<p>Welcome back $user ($email)</p>";
        }else{
            echo $_COOKIE['nag'];
            if($_COOKIE['nag'] == "0"){
                setcookie("nag", 5);
                echo "<br>Please Register, otherwise continue refreshing.";
                echo"<form action='$_SELF' method='POST'>";
                echo "Username: <input type='text' name='username' value=''<br><br>Email: <input type='text' name='email' value=''<br><br> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>";
                echo "</form>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    <p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`setcookie()` affects only the HTTP cookie header sent to the client and the new cookie value will be visible in PHP on the next request.

`$_COOKIE` variable is populated at the beginning of each request received by the web server from the cookie header received from the client.

This means that `setcookie()` doesn't update the `$_COOKIE`.

You will need to change the cookie altering code like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    setcookie("register", 1);
    $_COOKIE['register'] = 1;
    setcookie("username", $_POST['username']);
    $_COOKIE['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    setcookie("email", $_POST['email']);
    $_COOKIE['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    setcookie("nag","", time()-3600); 
    $_COOKIE['nag'] = time()-3600);
}
```

So if you are modifying the cookie data when processing a request and you want to access that updated data in that same request, remember to apply the change to `$_COOKIE` variable too.

Comment: It is very bad practice to modify superglobals like this. Have a look here as to why http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/76406/162446 it's one of the reasons setcookie exists in the first place

Comment: i modified my code as u suggested, but now i get a blank page with the resubmit pane when i click register.

Comment: I know. I've only answered the question. There are many programming and security flaws in the logic of the OP but that's not the question here.

Comment: Im not concerned with the security right now as it is a mini assignment to get used to working with cookies. i just need this to work. The question is how to make both the cookies work and display the corresponding msgs

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the page will resubmit the previous form data (hence the message in chrome), which will trigger your `isset($_POST['submit'])` again. You can fix this by using a redirect after a successful form submission. Example:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    setcookie("register", 1);
    setcookie("username", $_POST['username']);
    setcookie("email", $_POST['email']);
    setcookie("nag", "", time() - 3600);
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
...
```